# Design pattern for Swift using a protocol as a delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, type-erasure

**updated** Clarifying question to make clear this is an issue with a protocol that has a `typealias`, causing the general error of `can only be used as a generic constraint`.

I have the following class/protocol pattern:

```
protocol Storage { /* ... */ }
protocol StorageView { 
   typealias StorageType: Storage
   /* ... */
}

class StorageColumnView<StorageType:Storage>: StorageView { /* ... */ }
class SomeStorage: Storage { /* ... */ }
```

and I want to define a class that combines my `Storage` class with `View` class. Ideally, it would look something like:

```
class MyClass<S:StorageType> {
   var view:ViewType<S>
}
```

This won't compile because you can't specify a variable's type based on a protocol. After searching around, the general answer I found was to use type-erasure and make a `AnyView` class. However, such an approach seems cumbersome for a single variable (in theory this is the only place I'll use it) and difficult because `StorageView` has enough functionality to make wrapping each variable time consuming. Additionally, the methods of the view may get called a decent amount (yes, premature optimization is the root of all evil, but its `subscripts` will be called in loops), so I'm worried about the overhead.

Three alternative methods I'm currently investigating are:

(1) Declaring `view` as `AnyObject`, and then casting it to the correct type:

```
var view:AnyObject
// ...
view = StorageColumnView(/*...*/)
// ...
if let v = view as? StorageView {
   // operate on v
}
```

(2) Treating `view` as a function, and letting the type be defined using a closure:

```
var view: () -> StorageView
// ... 
view = { return StorageColumnView(self) }
/// ...
view().doX()
```

(3) Parameterizing `MyClass` by the `ViewType` rather than `Storage`:

```
class MyClass<V:ViewType> {
   typealias StorageType = ViewType.StorageType
}
```

I'm trying to evaluate which of the 3 options is best (in terms of Swift style as well as speed), or if there is another alternative I'm not aware of (*or* I really should just use type-erasure to solve this problem -- though it seems like `AnyObject` is essentially just that).

So:

1. Are there any major penalties for the first approach? Is this closer to c++'s `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`?
2. Is there a way to make the closure approach a little more user-friendly (i.e. I rather not require the user to actually pass in a closure, but rather the type). Maybe create a helper function that is a generic that then returns the type?
3. While the last solution is potentially the cleanest in amount of extra code required, it also requires a design that is against what I'm trying to do. The `ViewType` is really supposed to act like a delegate, and be fungible. Instead, I'm not creating a specific type of `MyClass` based on the `ViewType`.

Any and all opinions welcome on the best design pattern! I'm a little surprised that making a delegate-type pattern is so difficult (assuming I'm doing things correctly), considering that is primarily how Objective-C is used in Cocoa.

Also, does anyone know the rationale for not letting a variable to be defined as a protocol type that has a `typealias`? What's the underlying difference between a protocol with and without a `Self`?

Comment: "Also, does anyone know the rationale for not letting a variable to be defined as a protocol type?" ... Obviously, you can declare a variable as a protocol type (e.g. `var somVariable: ProtocolName`). But all it knows at that point is that it's some object that conforms to that protocol, and doesn't infer anything about whatever that object's base class is. Do I infer that you need both (i.e. not only that it conforms to some protocol, but also is some particular base class?). Is that what you're trying to do? I'm unclear as to the objective here.

Comment: (**edited** I was too quick to reply, my original question was correct) Sorry, you are correct -- I left out an important detail. The issue is that my protocol has a `typealias` which causes it to have a Self, and thus can only be used as a generic constraint. I'll update my question to reflect that detail.

Comment: Never mind, I did include the `typealias`. If the `typealias` weren't there, you would be correct. However, with it, you can do `var foo:proto` without getting the error about only being able to be used as a generic constraint.